# How do I make an ECMAScript6 function return from a loop when a condition is true?

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have this simple problem and I can't wrap my head around it.
I'm looping over a resultset returned from the database to see if the username is taken. If it's found, then the function should return an error and the user shouldn't be allowed to sign up. It works for a second, but then the state value doesn't update, so the function keeps on going and doesn't return when it finds that the username is taken and it signs up the user anyway.

```
  const [status, setStatus] = React.useState({ text: "", color: "" });
  const [newUser, setNewUser] = React.useState({
    Username: "",
    Password: "",
    admin: false,
    wishlist: [],
    cart: [],
  });

const Signup = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setStatus({});
    const srcData = await getDocs(collection(db, "users"));
    const id = srcData.size + 1;
    debugger;
    srcData.forEach((doc) => {
      const info = doc.data();
      console.log(info);
      if (info.Username === newUser.Username) {
        setStatus({
          text: "this userName is taken, please try a new UserName",
          color: "#CE000E",
          userTaken: true,
        });
      }
    });
    pushData(id, newUser);
  };
  const pushData = (id, data) => {
    if (status.userTaken === true) {
      /* here userTaken should be true but its false */ return;
    } else {
      setDoc(doc(db, "users", id.toString()), data);
      setStatus({
        text: "successfully signed up! you can now login!",
        color: "#019945",
      });
    }
  };
```

Comment: You seem to have posted more code than what would be reasonable for your issue. Please read [ask] and how to make a [mre]; providing a MRE helps users answer your question and future users relate to your issue.

Comment: thank you for this! but i try to give background on the variables used in the code so it can be as clear as possible

Comment: You'd be better off using `.some()` instead of `.forEach()`. Check the condition, and if `.some()` returns true you can return that error. The `.some()` call will stop iterating once the callback returns true.

Comment: Are you doing a `SELECT * FROM dbo.Users` on the backend?

Comment: @Pointy: You're right - Except I think this client-side code is pulling back far too much data from the server.

Comment: @JimG. yes totally possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so i managed to get it to work and the answer was pretty simple first i pinpointed the data i wanted, then i used some on it

```
const Signup = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setStatus({});
    const srcData = await getDocs(collection(db, "users"));
    const cleanData = [];
    const id = srcData.size + 1;
    srcData.forEach((doc) => {
      const info = doc.data();
      cleanData.push(info);
      
    });
    if (
      cleanData.some((data) => {
        return data.Username === newUser.Username;
      })
    ) {
      setStatus({
        text: "this userName is taken, please try a new UserName",
        color: "#CE000E",
      });
      return;
    } else {
      setDoc(doc(db, "users", id.toString()), data);
      setStatus({
        text: "successfully signed up! you can now login!",
        color: "#019945",
      });
    }
  };
```